# php change variable multiple times on a page by adding new below

Tags: php, variables, rename, multiple-instances

Does anyone know if its bad practice to do the below? If so is there an alternative to what I'm trying to achieve? (below is a simplified version of what I would be using)

```
<?php $projectTitle = "my title"; ?>
<h3><?php echo $projectTitle ?></h3>
<img src="bla.jpg" title="<?php echo $projectTitle ?> />
<img src="bla2.jpg" title="<?php echo $projectTitle ?> />
<img src="bla3.jpg" title="<?php echo $projectTitle ?> />

<?php $projectTitle = "my updated title"; ?>
<h3><?php echo $projectTitle ?></h3>
<img src="bla.jpg" title="<?php echo $projectTitle ?> />
<img src="bla2.jpg" title="<?php echo $projectTitle ?> />
<img src="bla3.jpg" title="<?php echo $projectTitle ?> />
```

and so on. Basically I want to just add for each project block the title once and have it carry out to where its called below until the next project where the project title would change.

I have tested this out and it works fine, but I'm not sure if there will be any unforeseen consequences or if there is a better way.

Comment: When you say, "do the below," are you asking if it's okay to call `echo` multiple times?

Comment: Why should that have bad consequences? Better overwriting the variables then creating new ones, which takes longer.

Comment: No, rdlowrey was asking if its okay to overwrite the variable just by placing them below each other in the code. The "$projectTitle =" part of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's okay. It makes your life easier and causes no harm at all

Answer (score 2):

I don't quite understand your question, but maybe this helps. Put all your project titles in an array and do a foreach:

```
<?php
$titles = array('my title', 'my updated title');
foreach ($titles as $title) {
?>
<h3><?php echo $title ?></h3>
<img src="bla.jpg" title="<?php echo $title ?> />
<img src="bla2.jpg" title="<?php echo $title ?> />
<img src="bla3.jpg" title="<?php echo $title ?> />
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: That would work but I need to have the title for each image and h tag below the title the same. Then in the next block change it. So according to my example it would be the same echo 4 times then the next project block below have a different echo 4 times.

Answer (score 1):

Try to make a little php file like this :

```
<?php $projectTitle = $title; ?>
<h3><?php echo $projectTitle ?></h3>
<img src="bla.jpg" title="<?php echo $projectTitle ?> />
<img src="bla2.jpg" title="<?php echo $projectTitle ?> />
<img src="bla3.jpg" title="<?php echo $projectTitle ?> />
```

And in your main file do this :

```
$title = "my updated title"
include(".../projet.php");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that it's ok to call `echo` multiple times, but if you always call the IMGs with the same structure, maybe this little function will help you:

```
function addIMG( $imgs, $projectTitle ){
  foreach($imgs as $array)
    echo "<img> src=\"$array\" title=\"$projectTitle\" /> \n";
}

// Then to call:
$projectTitle = $title;
$imgs = array('bla.jpg','bla2.jpg', 'bla3.jpg');
echo addIMG( $imgs, $projectTitle );
```

That's a start; feel free to use/change it at your will.